# how to get proxy in python on scraping with request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how to get proxy randomly? and get only one?

I've made the code as below but I don't know how to get the proxy randomly, and I want to get the proxy also based on the page, anyone know how?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?anon=34#list'

r = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you get going.  Check out the table section, will be most salient to what you're trying to do.

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup

You need to get further into the soup and put your desired data into some kind of container to then be able to extract an item randomly from it.

getting further into the soup:

```
# this will find the table block on the proxy url site 
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "table_block"})

# this will find all the 'tr' elements in the table variable and put them in a list
data = table.tbody.findAll("tr")

# separate the elements you care about from the data list 
# pick proxy list or from write your data to file 
# use a module like random to aid in picking a random proxy from your list or file
```

"Getting the proxy based on the page" is really non-specific - based on what page? What condition on the page? Add a little more detail (and make sure to check other answers on stack overflow) to help people better answer your questions and to help improve question quality on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try out this library, [proxy-randomizer](https://pypi.org/project/proxy-randomizer)

You will be able to get a pool of free proxies to use in any of your requests. Then you can use a hash map to use them base on the page you want to scrape

```py
from proxy_randomizer import RegisteredProviders
import requests

rp = RegisteredProviders()
rp.parse_providers()

for proxy in rp.proxies:

     proxies     = {"https": proxy.get_proxy()}
     response    = requests.get("http://google.com", proxies=proxies)
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author.*